# Why does adding a break statement significantly slow down the Numba function?

Tags: python, performance, numba

I have the following Numba function:

```py
@numba.njit
def count_in_range(arr, min_value, max_value):
    count = 0
    for a in arr:
        if min_value < a < max_value:
            count += 1
    return count
```

It counts how many values are in the range in the array.

However, I realized that I only needed to determine if they existed.
So I modified it as follows:

```py
@numba.njit
def count_in_range2(arr, min_value, max_value):
    count = 0
    for a in arr:
        if min_value < a < max_value:
            count += 1
            break  # <---- break here
    return count
```

Then, this function becomes **slower** than before the change.
Under certain conditions, it can be surprisingly more than 10 times slower.

Benchmark code:

```py
from timeit import timeit

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
arr = rng.random(10 * 1000 * 1000)

# To compare on even conditions, choose the condition that does not terminate early.
min_value = 0.5
max_value = min_value - 1e-10
assert not np.any(np.logical_and(min_value <= arr, arr <= max_value))

n = 100
for f in (count_in_range, count_in_range2):
    f(arr, min_value, max_value)
    elapsed = timeit(lambda: f(arr, min_value, max_value), number=n) / n
    print(f"{f.__name__}: {elapsed * 1000:.3f} ms")
```

Result:

```
count_in_range: 3.351 ms
count_in_range2: 42.312 ms
```

Further experimenting, I found that the speed varies greatly depending on the search range (i.e. `min_value` and `max_value`).

At various search ranges:

```
count_in_range2: 5.802 ms, range: (0.0, -1e-10)
count_in_range2: 15.408 ms, range: (0.1, 0.09999999990000001)
count_in_range2: 29.571 ms, range: (0.25, 0.2499999999)
count_in_range2: 42.514 ms, range: (0.5, 0.4999999999)
count_in_range2: 24.427 ms, range: (0.75, 0.7499999999)
count_in_range2: 12.547 ms, range: (0.9, 0.8999999999)
count_in_range2: 5.747 ms, range: (1.0, 0.9999999999)
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

---

I am using Numba 0.58.1 under Python 3.10.11.
Confirmed on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.

---

## EDIT:

As an appendix to Jérôme Richard's answer:

As he pointed out in the comments, the performance difference that depends on a search range is likely due to branch prediction.

For example, when `min_value` is `0.1`, `min_value < a` has a 90% chance of being true, and `a < max_value` has a 90% chance of being false. So mathematically it can be predicted correctly with 81% accuracy. I have no idea how the CPU does this, but I have come up with a way to check if this logic is correct.

First, by partitioning the array with values above and below the threshold, and second, by mixing it with a certain probability of error. When the array is partitioned, the number of branch prediction misses should be unaffected by the threshold. When we include errors in it, the number of misses should increase depending on the errors.

Here is the updated benchmark code:

```py
from timeit import timeit
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.njit
def count_in_range(arr, min_value, max_value):
    count = 0
    for a in arr:
        if min_value < a < max_value:
            count += 1
    return count


@numba.njit
def count_in_range2(arr, min_value, max_value):
    count = 0
    for a in arr:
        if min_value < a < max_value:
            count += 1
            break  # <---- break here
    return count


def partition(arr, threshold):
    """Place the elements smaller than the threshold in the front and the elements larger than the threshold in the back."""
    less = arr[arr < threshold]
    more = arr[~(arr < threshold)]
    return np.concatenate((less, more))


def partition_with_error(arr, threshold, error_rate):
    """Same as partition, but includes errors with a certain probability."""
    less = arr[arr < threshold]
    more = arr[~(arr < threshold)]
    less_error, less_correct = np.split(less, [int(len(less) * error_rate)])
    more_error, more_correct = np.split(more, [int(len(more) * error_rate)])
    mostly_less = np.concatenate((less_correct, more_error))
    mostly_more = np.concatenate((more_correct, less_error))
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    rng.shuffle(mostly_less)
    rng.shuffle(mostly_more)
    out = np.concatenate((mostly_less, mostly_more))
    assert np.array_equal(np.sort(out), np.sort(arr))
    return out


def bench(f, arr, min_value, max_value, n=10, info=""):
    f(arr, min_value, max_value)
    elapsed = timeit(lambda: f(arr, min_value, max_value), number=n) / n
    print(f"{f.__name__}: {elapsed * 1000:.3f} ms, min_value: {min_value:.1f}, {info}")


def main():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    arr = rng.random(10 * 1000 * 1000)
    thresholds = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)

    print("#", "-" * 10, "As for comparison", "-" * 10)
    bench(
        count_in_range,
        arr,
        min_value=0.5,
        max_value=0.5 - 1e-10,
    )

    print("\n#", "-" * 10, "Random Data", "-" * 10)
    for min_value in thresholds:
        bench(
            count_in_range2,
            arr,
            min_value=min_value,
            max_value=min_value - 1e-10,
        )

    print("\n#", "-" * 10, "Partitioned (Yet Still Random) Data", "-" * 10)
    for min_value in thresholds:
        bench(
            count_in_range2,
            partition(arr, threshold=min_value),
            min_value=min_value,
            max_value=min_value - 1e-10,
        )

    print("\n#", "-" * 10, "Partitioned Data with Probabilistic Errors", "-" * 10)
    for ratio in thresholds:
        bench(
            count_in_range2,
            partition_with_error(arr, threshold=0.5, error_rate=ratio),
            min_value=0.5,
            max_value=0.5 - 1e-10,
            info=f"error: {ratio:.0%}",
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
# ---------- As for comparison ----------
count_in_range: 3.518 ms, min_value: 0.5, 

# ---------- Random Data ----------
count_in_range2: 5.958 ms, min_value: 0.0, 
count_in_range2: 15.390 ms, min_value: 0.1, 
count_in_range2: 24.715 ms, min_value: 0.2, 
count_in_range2: 33.749 ms, min_value: 0.3, 
count_in_range2: 40.007 ms, min_value: 0.4, 
count_in_range2: 42.168 ms, min_value: 0.5, 
count_in_range2: 37.427 ms, min_value: 0.6, 
count_in_range2: 28.763 ms, min_value: 0.7, 
count_in_range2: 20.089 ms, min_value: 0.8, 
count_in_range2: 12.638 ms, min_value: 0.9, 
count_in_range2: 5.876 ms, min_value: 1.0, 

# ---------- Partitioned (Yet Still Random) Data ----------
count_in_range2: 6.006 ms, min_value: 0.0, 
count_in_range2: 5.999 ms, min_value: 0.1, 
count_in_range2: 5.953 ms, min_value: 0.2, 
count_in_range2: 5.952 ms, min_value: 0.3, 
count_in_range2: 5.940 ms, min_value: 0.4, 
count_in_range2: 6.870 ms, min_value: 0.5, 
count_in_range2: 5.939 ms, min_value: 0.6, 
count_in_range2: 5.896 ms, min_value: 0.7, 
count_in_range2: 5.899 ms, min_value: 0.8, 
count_in_range2: 5.880 ms, min_value: 0.9, 
count_in_range2: 5.884 ms, min_value: 1.0, 

# ---------- Partitioned Data with Probabilistic Errors ----------
# Note that min_value = 0.5 in all the following.
count_in_range2: 5.939 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 0%
count_in_range2: 14.015 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 10%
count_in_range2: 22.599 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 20%
count_in_range2: 31.763 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 30%
count_in_range2: 39.391 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 40%
count_in_range2: 42.227 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 50%
count_in_range2: 38.748 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 60%
count_in_range2: 31.758 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 70%
count_in_range2: 22.600 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 80%
count_in_range2: 14.090 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 90%
count_in_range2: 6.027 ms, min_value: 0.5, error: 100%
```

I am satisfied with this result.

Comment: Numba relies on recognizing code patterns to transform slow procedural Python bytecode into vector-based NumPy/GPU-acceleratable code blocks. By inserting that `break` statement you break the recognizable code pattern so your code can no longer benefit from GPU acceleration.

Comment: @blhsing No, this is completely wrong! Numba does not transform a CPU code into a GPU code or a Numpy one. There is no such pattern recognition. GPU codes are explicit ones. This is a common wrong belief. Numba's `njit` converts a Python CPU code to a native CPU code using a JIT called LLVMLite which use LLVM (hence the name). The only non-trivial transformation are the ones related to parallelism which require the flag `parallel=True` which is not even set here. In this case, all the complex transformations comes from LLVM (mainly) and the Python bytecode compilation to LLVM IR.

Comment: If you do `print(count_in_range.inspect_llvm())` and `print(count_in_range2.inspect_llvm())` afterwards, you will see that the compiler vectorized (unrolled) the loop in `count_in_range`. With `break` in `count_in_range2` the compiler didn't do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Numba uses LLVM which not able to automatically vectorize the code when there is a `break`. One way to fix this is to compute the operation chunk by chunk.

---

**Numba is based on the LLVM compiler toolchain** to compile the Python code to a native one. Numlba generates an LLVM intermediate representation (IR) from the Python code and then gives that to LLVM so it can generate a fast native code. All the low-level optimizations are made by LLVM, not actually Numba itself. In this case, **LLVM is not able to automatically vectorize the code when there is a `break`**. Numba doesn't do any pattern recognition here nor run any code on the GPU (basic `numba.njit` code is always run on the CPU).

Note that "vectorization" in this context means generating [SIMD instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) from a scalar IR code. This word has a different meaning in the context of a Numpy Python code (which means calling native functions so to reduce the overhead but the native functions are not necessarily using SIMD instructions).

---

### Under the hood

I reproduced the issue with Clang which is a C++ compiler using also the LLVM toolchain. Here is the equivalent C++ code:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

int64_t count_in_range(const std::vector<double>& arr, double min_value, double max_value)
{
    int64_t count = 0;

    for(int64_t i=0 ; i<arr.size() ; ++i)
    {
        double a = arr[i];

        if (min_value < a && a < max_value)
        {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

This code [results](https://godbolt.org/z/4fPjab5E1) in the following assembly main loop:

```
.LBB0_6:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovupd ymm8, ymmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax]
        vmovupd ymm9, ymmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax + 32]
        vmovupd ymm10, ymmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax + 64]
        vmovupd ymm11, ymmword ptr [rcx + 8*rax + 96]
        vcmpltpd        ymm12, ymm2, ymm8
        vcmpltpd        ymm13, ymm2, ymm9
        vcmpltpd        ymm14, ymm2, ymm10
        vcmpltpd        ymm15, ymm2, ymm11
        vcmpltpd        ymm8, ymm8, ymm4
        vandpd  ymm8, ymm12, ymm8
        vpsubq  ymm3, ymm3, ymm8
        vcmpltpd        ymm8, ymm9, ymm4
        vandpd  ymm8, ymm13, ymm8
        vpsubq  ymm5, ymm5, ymm8
        vcmpltpd        ymm8, ymm10, ymm4
        vandpd  ymm8, ymm14, ymm8
        vpsubq  ymm6, ymm6, ymm8
        vcmpltpd        ymm8, ymm11, ymm4
        vandpd  ymm8, ymm15, ymm8
        vpsubq  ymm7, ymm7, ymm8
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rsi, rax
        jne     .LBB0_6
```

The instructions `vmovupd`, `vcmpltpd` and `vandpd`, etc. show that the assembly code fully uses **SIMD instructions**.

If we add a `break`, then it is not the case any-more:

```
.LBB0_4:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovsd  xmm2, qword ptr [rcx + 8*rsi]   # xmm2 = mem[0],zero
        vcmpltpd        xmm3, xmm2, xmm1
        vcmpltpd        xmm2, xmm0, xmm2
        vandpd  xmm2, xmm2, xmm3
        vmovq   rdi, xmm2
        sub     rax, rdi
        test    dil, 1
        jne     .LBB0_2
        lea     rdi, [rsi + 1]
        cmp     rdx, rsi
        mov     rsi, rdi
        jne     .LBB0_4
```

Here `vmovsd` moves a scalar value in the loop (and `rsi` is incremented of 1 per loop iteration). This later code is significantly less efficient. Indeed, it operates on only one item at a time for each iteration as opposed to 16 items for the previous code.

We can use the compilation flag `-Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize` to check if the loop is indeed not vectorized. Clang explicitly reports:

> remark: loop not vectorized [-Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize

To know the reason, we can use the flag `-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize`:

> loop not vectorized: **could not determine number of loop iterations** [-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize]

Thus, we can conclude that LLVM optimizer does not support this pattern of code.

---

### Solution

One way to avoid this issue is to **operate on chunks**. The computation of each chunk can be fully vectorized by Clang and you can break the condition early at the first chunk.

Here is an untested code:

```py
@numba.njit
def count_in_range_faster(arr, min_value, max_value):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, arr.size, 16):
        if arr.size - i >= 16:
            # Optimized SIMD-friendly computation of 1 chunk of size 16
            tmp_view = arr[i:i+16]
            for j in range(0, 16):
                if min_value < tmp_view[j] < max_value:
                    count += 1
            if count > 0:
                return 1
        else:
            # Fallback implementation (variable-sized chunk)
            for j in range(i, arr.size):
                if min_value < arr[j] < max_value:
                    count += 1
            if count > 0:
                return 1
    return 0
```

The [C++ equivalent code is properly vectorized](https://godbolt.org/z/ez1Tq91nT). One need to check this is also true for the Numba code with the `count_in_range_faster.inspect_llvm()` but the following timings show that the above implementation is faster than the two others.

---

### Performance results

Here are results on a machine with a Xeon W-2255 CPU using Numba 0.56.0:

```
count_in_range:          7.112 ms
count_in_range2:        35.317 ms
count_in_range_faster:   5.827 ms     <----------
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer. It makes a lot of sense if SIMD is involved. And the solution you provided works perfectly. However, one thing I still don't understand is that the performance of `count_in_range2` varies greatly depending on the input. In my benchmarks, its execution times vary from 2x to 12x compared to the `count_in_range`. I could not figure out why this happens from the C++ assembly code you provided. Am I missing something? Or is there some other optimization for the non-SIMD version in Numba?

Comment: In `count_in_range`, the array is fully travelled so the performance is dependent of the array size. In `count_in_range2` the performance is dependent of when the `break` is triggered (i.e. dependent of the content). For example, if `min_value < arr[0] < max_value` is true, then only one item is fetched from memory and not the others. This is generally one purpose of a `break` statement : speed up a computation by skipping the necessary remaining work. When the array is fully travelled in `count_in_range2`, the computation is much slower because of the scalar assembly code (versus SIMD).

Comment: Put it shortly, `count_in_range2` should be faster than `count_in_range` if the condition tends to be often true. Otherwise, `count_in_range` should be faster. My implementation should be faster than the two in nearly all cases.

Comment: "If `min_value < arr[0] < max_value` is true" Yes. But in my benchmark I set `max_value` to `min_value - 1e-10`. So `min_value < arr[0] < max_value` can never be true. Only one of them can be true, and its balance affects the performance. Of course, since it is an AND operation, if one of them is false, the other can be omitted, but I cannot think of that alone explaining the 7x difference ( `min_value=0.0` vs `min_value=0.5` ).

Comment: *"Only one of them can be true"* yes, but depending on its location, the number of read item will change and so the computational time. If you ensure the condition is false for all items (i.e. the function returns 0), then you should see a stable computational time assuming the performance instability are coming from this effect.

Comment: Note that other effect can cause performance instabilities. One of them is subnormal float operations : if values are very very small, it is often more expensive for the CPU to operate on such numbers. You can ensure there is no sub-normals by just setting to 0 the values that are very close to 0.

Comment: Last but not least, the scalar code contains multiple conditional branches that are data-dependent. Modern CPUs try to predict the outcomes of conditionals. If they fail to predict that correctly, then the condition is more expensive. Regarding the actual input, conditional instruction can be much more expensive. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) for more information about this. The SIMD-friendly code is branchless is does not suffer from this possible issue.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to assume that this is due to branch prediction. I have done additional research (I added the results to my post) and all my questions have been addressed. I appreciate your help.